# How to fix 'Cannot read property of undefined' error in Angular post request

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, http-post, angular-reactive-forms

I'm getting these errors and I'm not sure how to fix it. I am making a form that will make a post request to an API.

#### ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

#### ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'paymentMethod' of undefined

I am expecting:

```
createdBy: string from email input,
paymentMethod: string from paymentMethod select input,
```

But what I get is:

```
createdBy: null,
paymentMethod: null
```

Interfaces

```
export interface BillingForm {
    fullName: string;
    email: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
    paymentMethod: string;

  }

export interface Order {
  id?: number;
  companyId: number;
  created: string;
  createdBy: string;
  paymentMethod: string;
  totalPrice: number;
  status: number;
  orderRows: OrderRows[];
}
```

service.ts

```
public postOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
      console.log(order);
      return this.http.post<Order>(this.ordersURL, order, httpOptions).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('postOrder', order))
      );
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.shippingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
      paymentMethod: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }


  onSubmit(billingForm: BillingForm) {
    const order = this.newOrder(billingForm);

    this.productService.postOrder(order).subscribe (
      response => console.log('success', response),
      error => console.log('error', error)
    )

    this.submitted = true;

    if(this.shippingForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.success = true;

  }

  newOrder(billingForm: BillingForm ): Order {
    return {
      companyId: 6,
      created: moment().locale("sv").format("YYYY-MM-DDTLTS"),
      createdBy: billingForm.email,
      paymentMethod: billingForm.paymentMethod,
      totalPrice: this.totalPrice,
      status: 0,
      orderRows: this.orderRows

    }
  }

  get email() {
    return this.shippingForm.get("email") as FormControl;
  }

  get paymentMethod() {
    return this.shippingForm.get("paymentMethod") as FormControl;
  }
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="shippingForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(billingForm)">
        <h5 *ngIf="success">Your form is valid!</h5>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            <div *ngIf="submitted && shippingForm.controls.email.errors" class="error">
              <div *ngIf="shippingForm.controls.email.errors.required">Your email is required!</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="payment">Payment Method: </label>
            <select type="select" formControlName="paymentMethod" class="form-control" id="payment"
              aria-placeholder="Mastercard">
              <option selected> Choose...</option>
              <option *ngFor="let paymentMethod of paymentMethods">
                {{ paymentMethod }}
              </option>
            </select>
            <div *ngIf="submitted && shippingForm.controls.paymentMethod.errors" class="error">
              <div *ngIf="shippingForm.controls.paymentMethod.errors.required">Your preferred payment method is required!</div>
            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code in newOrder function.

createdBy: billingForm.**value**.email,

paymentMethod: billingForm.**value**.paymentMethod,

Comment: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'BillingForm'

Comment: If you need values from the form you are submitting then you should access shipping form values like : this.shippingForm.value.email and this.shippingForm.value.paymentMethod

Comment: omg! That works. It was so obvious! Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
  newOrder(billingForm: BillingForm ): Order {
    return {
      companyId: 6,
      created: moment().locale("sv").format("YYYY-MM-DDTLTS"),
      createdBy: billingForm.email, // <--- HERE
      paymentMethod: billingForm.paymentMethod, // <--- HERE
      totalPrice: this.totalPrice,
      status: 0,
      orderRows: this.orderRows

    }
  }
```

The two lines depend on `billingForm`, and it seems that this `billingForm` doesn't have the `email` & `paymentMethod` values. Log it to be sure.

Comment: How would you suggest me to do?

Comment: @Nebula give it a fallback value : `createdBy: billingForm.email: billingForm && billingForm.meail || 'defaultvalue'`

Comment: I get a lot of red underlines by writing it like that. I might misurdestood what you meant

Comment: `createdBy: billingForm && billingForm.meail || 'defaultvalue'`. @Nebula, sorry, forgot to delete the first part  !

Comment: ok, that seems to be taking the 'defaultvalue' string and not the email that I write in my form. But the errors are gone at least. What am I missing?

Comment: I see. So why is it not taking the values from the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]="shippingForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(billingForm)">
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this `billingForm` is nowhere defined. So `onSubmit` method gets called with `undefined` as argument.

`shippingForm` is defined (and it's the one connected to the template), I'm guessing you meant `onSubmit(shippingForm)`.

Comment: Even if I switch to 'onSubmit(shippingForm)' the result is the same